# Facebook xhr login: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have this problem, when I try to log in users on my website through facebook using XHR my request gets blocked, however if I copy the URL of the XHR request and paste it in the browser I get logged in.

So here's a simple schematic:

[image]

Why is xhr getting blocked on the same url a browser can access?

Comment: When you redirect and the browser makes the request so that the user can see it, there is no "cross-origin", but when you send the xhr then the origin is your website and then CORS comes into the game and the fb server has to excplicitly allow your url as origin for the request.

Comment: @StefanHegny well I have configured my facebook app to allow requests from my site's URL but I'm still getting intercepted, is there anything I can do?

Comment: it's not your app, it's the facebook server that disallows the request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is xhr getting blocked on the same url a browser can access?

Because it is a cross-domain request, and as such the remote party would have to *allow* that request first, which is what is referred to as CORS.

Facebook does not allow its login dialog to be loaded via script from different domains – for the obvious reason that users need to be able to be verify which site they are sending their login credentials to via the browser address bar, to avoid phishing.

You **can not** load the FB login dialog via XHR/AJAX in the background; you **need** to call/redirect to it in the top window instance.

Comment: How do you do that

Comment: @Sam not sure what exactly the question is – you build the login dialog URL (or have a SDK/library do it for you), and then you send the user there, by having them click a link pointing to it, or via `location.href=…` in client-side JS, or via a server-side redirect.